# How to integrate these: $\iiiint_A\frac{t^2dtdxdydz}{t^2+2x^2+3y^2+4z^2}$ and another one in wolfram alpha?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, wolfram-alpha

I tried different methods but I cannot put following integrals into Wolfram Alpha in order to find ou results.
$$
\iiiint_A\frac{t^2\,dt\,dx\,dy\,dz}{t^2+2x^2+3y^2+4z^2},
$$
where $A=\{(t,x,y,z): t^2+2x^2+3y^2+4z^2<1\}$
and $$\iiiint r^5\sin^2(\alpha_3)\cos(\alpha_2)\cos^2(\alpha_3)\,dr\,d\alpha_1\,d\alpha_2\,d\alpha_3,$$
 where $r\in(0,1), ~\alpha_1\in(0,2\pi); ~\alpha_2,\alpha_3\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Thank you for help.

Comment: You need to find the right coordinates to describe $A$

Comment: elliptical coordinates will do the job

Comment: @Masacroso No, I want to integrate once over $A$.

Comment: Is in not possible to integrate in wolfram alpha without setting cooridantes first?

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk I think that it is best that you ask this question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) and after use the wolfram language in wolfram alpha or in [wolfram programming lab](https://lab.open.wolframcloud.com/app/).

Comment: Integrate over region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don\t know if it works in Wolfram Alpha, but in Mathematica the second integral can be calculated by

> Integrate[
>   r^5 Sin^2 (x) Cos (y) Cos^2 (z), {r, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, -Pi/2, 
>    Pi/2}, {z, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]

(But is also easy to see that this integral vanishes)

For the first integral, I dont know how to do it directly, but if you use coordinate transformations $x\to \frac 1 {\sqrt{2}} x$, $y \to \frac {1} {\sqrt {3}} y$, $z \to \frac 1 {\sqrt4} z$, then $A\to B_1(0)$ and you can use polar coordinates for $\mathbb{R}^4$ and use the same syntax as for the second example.

Comment: You mean rather $x\to \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} x$ and so on, right?

Comment: yes, i will fix it

Answer (score 1):

Through the substitutions $t=a,\; x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}b,\; y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}c,\; z=\frac{1}{2}d $
 **and symmetry** the given integral boils down to:
$$ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{6}}\iiiint_{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2<1}\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}\,d\mu\\ = \frac{1}{8\sqrt{6}}\iiiint_{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2<1}\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}\,d\mu$$
and that is just $\frac{1}{8\sqrt{6}}$ times the (hyper-)volume of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^4$, i.e. $\large\color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{16\sqrt{6}}}$.